# stat_pvalue_manually and stat_compare_means with Tukey HSD

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, box, tukey

I am using ggpubr and ggplot2. First I did a anova test on my 3 clusters and now I would like to include my p-adj values of the TukeyHSD test in my box plot by using

> stat_compare_means
> or
> stat_pvalue_manually

since I found out that Tukey test cannot be shown with stat_compare_means unfortunately..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This was asked a long time ago but in case somebody comes across it, here is an example with the `iris` dataset since there was none shown in your question. First, load the three libraries shown. Then fit the ANOVA in the next code chunk, fit the Tukey test with additional p value/xy positions in the data, then add them as labels like so:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)

#### Fit Data ####
fit <- iris %>% 
  anova_test(Sepal.Length ~ Species) %>% 
  add_significance()

#### Run Tukey ###
tukey <- iris %>% 
  tukey_hsd(Sepal.Length ~ Species) %>% 
  add_significance() %>% 
  add_xy_position()

#### Plot ####
ggboxplot(iris,
          x="Species",
          y="Sepal.Length")+
  stat_pvalue_manual(tukey,
                     hide.ns = T)+
  labs(subtitle = get_test_label(fit,
                            detailed = TRUE),
  caption = get_pwc_label(tukey))
```

It should turn out like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
library(ggplot2)

library(ggpubr)
library(tidyverse)

library(rstatix)

tukey <- diamonds %>%
  tukey_hsd(price ~ cut) %>%
  add_significance() %>%
  add_xy_position() %>%
  filter(group1 == "Fair")

diamonds %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_rev(cut), y = price)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_pvalue_manual(tukey,
                     hide.ns = T,
                     label = "p.adj")
```

[image]